# Error when saving parent NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using the following MOC setup:

1. Parent - using persistent store coordinator (Main queue)
2. Child1 - using parent (Private queue)
3. Child2 - using parent (Private queue)
4. Child3 - using parent (Private queue)

Children periodically save their changes and respawn as new snapshots of the main MOC when needed.

All works fine until I try to save the main MOC. This is the error message I get: `Cannot update object that was never inserted`

> Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x1758e200 {NSAffectedObjectsErrorKey=(
>       " (entity: Event; id: 0x1767d3d0  ; data: {\n    dateBegin = nil;\n    dateEnd = nil;\n    identifier = nil;\n    identifierBegin = 0;\n    isProcessed = 1;\n    nPhotos = 0;\n    name = nil;\n    photos = \"\";\n})"
>   ), NSUnderlyingException=Cannot update object that was never inserted.},

It doesn't happen all the time and removing time consuming operations makes it happen less frequently. I also noticed that during the exception the other MOCs are busy saving or querying. I use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`for all MOC related operations to run on the right queue.

If relevant, `child1` imports base objects, `child2` creates events, `child3` processes the events and updates both `Event` and the base object. `parent` is used to persist tge data to disk and update the UI. Eliminating the thread that uses `child3` solves the problem but I'm not convinced it isn't a timing issue.

Any ideas why this happens?

**Edit**

I think I found the source of the problem. Now looking for solutions.

`child3` updated an `Event` and tried to save the change to `parent` while `child2` decided to delete the `Event` and already saved this change. To the save is trying to update a non-existing object. Strangely the error ocurs only when I tried to save `parent` to the PSC.

Comment: Qu.1 - Have you considered using a single `NSManagedObjectContext` for the tasks "import base objects", "creates events" and "process the events and updates..."? Qu.2 - Have you considered using a stacked `performBlockAndWait`, so that `child1` must save first, then `child2`, then `child3`?

Comment: #1 - This is what I'm using as a workaround. It works but it adds coupling between the tasks. In addition when task1 saves context intermediate changes of task2 are also saved which can affect UI and other CoreData consumers. #2 In my case the tasks don't know about each other.

Comment: While the tasks don't know about each other, is it important that they complete in a certain order, as there are necessary relationships to populate for the `NSManagedObject`, at least in `child3` (event and base object update)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same to the error message and in my case the problem was in storing reference to temporary (not permanent which is generated after saving context) ObjectID, trying to get object from another context (objectWithID:) with id and then performing changes to this object. Save method gave me the same result.

Are you by any chance accessing objects between contexts by referencing to ObjectID?